# R problems with filling a vector using a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm iterating over a vector, for each element I look something up in a table by rowname and copy the return into a different vector. The following code is used for that

```
gs1 = function(p)
{
output <- character() #empty vector to which results will be forwarded

for (i in 1:length(p)) {
test <- p[i]
index <- which(rownames(conditions) == test)
toappend <- conditions[index,3] #working
output[i] <- toappend
print(paste(p[i],index,toappend,output[i]))
}   
return(output)
}
```

All it spits out is a vector with numbers....while all other variables seems to contain the correct information (as checked by the print function)
I have the feeling I'm doing something terribly wrong in filling the output vector... I could also use

```
output <- c(output,toappend)
```

But that gives me exactly the same, wrong and strange output.

All help is very much appreciated!

**Output example**

```
> gs1 = function(p)
+ {
+ output <- character() #empty vector to which results will be pasted
+ 
+ for (i in 1:length(p)) {
+ test <- p[i]
+ index <- which(rownames(conditions) == test)
+ toappend <- conditions[index,3] #working
+ 
+ output <- c(output,toappend)
+ output[i] <- toappend
+ print(paste(p[i],index,toappend,output[i],sep=","))
+ }
+ return(output)
+ }
> ###########################
> test <- colnames(tri.data.1)
> gs1(test)
[1] "Row.names,,,NA"
[1] "GSM235482,1,Glc A,5"
[1] "GSM235484,2,Glc A,5"
[1] "GSM235485,3,Glc A,5"
[1] "GSM235487,4,Xyl A,21"
[1] "GSM235489,5,Xyl A,21"
[1] "GSM235491,6,Xyl A,21"
[1] "GSM297399,7,pH 2.5,12"
[1] "GSM297400,8,pH 2.5,12"
[1] "GSM297401,9,pH 2.5,12"
[1] "GSM297402,10,pH 4.5,13"
[1] "GSM297403,11,pH 4.5,13"
[1] "GSM297404,12,pH 4.5,13"
[1] "GSM297563,13,pH 6.0,14"
[1] "GSM297564,14,pH 6.0,14"
[1] "GSM297565,15,pH 6.0,14"
 [1] "5"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "21" "21" "21" "12" "12" "12" "13" "13" "13" "14" "14" "14"
```

Comment: Some sample data would be welcome. What is conditions? What are you trying to do?

Comment: show us in what way is `output` wrong? What are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: then it is exactly as Joris diagnosed. Look at `str(conditions)` and note what data type the third entry/variable is. It will be `factor`. R stores these internally as numbers but prints them with nice labels. You are getting the internal numbers not the level form. `as.character()` will solve that, or alternatively, when you read in the data, look at argument `stringsAsFactors` in `?read.table`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very likely you're using a data frame and not a table, and as likely your third column is not a character vector but a factor. And there is no need to write that function, you could easily obtain the wanted by:

```
conditions[X,3]
```

with X being a character vector of row names. eg :

```
X <- data.frame(
  var1 = 1:10,
  var2 = 10:1,
  var3 = letters[1:10],
  row.names=LETTERS[1:10]
)
> test <- c("F","D","A")
> X[test,3]
[1] f d a
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
```

To get it in characters:

```
> as.character(X[test,3])
[1] "f" "d" "a"
```

Comment: +1 for the simplification! That dawned on me as I was adding something to make it less cryptic following your comment.

Comment: omg... it turns out I can rewrite the loop: conditions[colnames(tri.data.1),3]

Comment: @Timtico : indeed, and welcome to the power of R. :-) Vectorization and indices are really a blessing. You might want to put some time in checking the help files and introduction notes of R to get yourself acquainted with those, you'll never regret it.

Comment: I was forced into R because of the Bioconductor packages, but I don't regret it at all. I know it's a bad habit making loops, but I'm just too used to it :)

Comment: Althought I still cannot fully understand why the loop didnt work in my case. I consider Joris' answer as the most appropiate, i should stay away from the looping when I can.

Comment: @Timtico : as I and Gavin said already, your 3d variable is a factor. The stored value is a number there, but every number has a label. Now toappend still has the label, but the label is lost when you add the value to a character vector. Hence, only the number remains. if you do str(conditions) you'll see that.

Answer (score 3):

[Joris' comments suggest I was too cryptic, so some additional explanation]:

Effectively, if we ignore the processing in your loop, this is what you have:

```
> p <- 1:10
> gs1 <- function(p) {
+     output <- character()
+     for(i in seq_along(p))  {
+         output[i] <- p[i] * 10
+         print(output)
+     }
+     return(output)
+ }
> foo <- gs1(p)
[1] "10"
[1] "10" "20"
[1] "10" "20" "30"
[1] "10" "20" "30" "40"
[1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50"
[1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60"
[1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70"
[1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" "80"
[1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" "80" "90"
[1] "10"  "20"  "30"  "40"  "50"  "60"  "70"  "80"  "90"  "100"
> foo
[1] "10"  "20"  "30"  "40"  "50"  "60"  "70"  "80"  "90"  "100"
```

So `gs1` is returning something, and `output` is being filled, as long as `toappend` is acharacter or can be *coerced* to character to go into `output`. Now, if `toappend` is not what you think it is, then that is where you will start to get problems.

I see two potential problems; i) `toappend` is actually a factor (which is something Joris mentions too) and you are getting the numerical equivalent of the internal coding for that level. In which case

```
ouput[i] <- as.character(toappend)
```

should suffice, or ii) `index` is greater than length 1 and you are getting more elements in the vector that you expect and thus at the next iteration you are overwriting them.

Are you **sure** `toappend` is a single character vector of length 1? How about you show us the incorrect output (edit your Question and add the output from the function) and tell us why it is wrong!

Of course, this can all be simplified to `conditions[p, 3]` and no need for a loop but I assume your actual functions is more complex?

---

#### Note on setting up loops

As for loops in general, you make the mistake of not preallocating storage. You shouldn't do things the way you are. Notice how at each iteration R is having to grow `output` by one element per iteration. The same would be true of your `output <- c(output, toappend)` idiom. This involves lots of redundant copying of the vector which bogs loops down. Instead, allocate enough storage up front and fill `output` as you are doing. E.g.:

```
gs2 <- function(p) {
    output <- character(length = length(p))
    for(i in seq_along(p))  {
        output[i] <- p[i] * 10
        print(output)
    }
    return(output)
}
```

which produces this output:

```
> gs2(p)
 [1] "10" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [1] "10" "20" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [1] "10" "20" "30" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [1] "10" "20" "30" "40" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60" ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" ""   ""   ""  
 [1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" "80" ""   ""  
 [1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" "80" "90" ""  
 [1] "10"  "20"  "30"  "40"  "50"  "60"  "70"  "80"  "90"  "100"
 [1] "10"  "20"  "30"  "40"  "50"  "60"  "70"  "80"  "90"  "100"
```

The duplicated last line is due to auto-printing of the object (`output`) returned from the function.

Comment: @Gavin : errr, you lost me there. Your function hardly seems even remotely related to the one of OP. His print statement is for debugging purposes I suppose. If you run his code (change the conditions to X) on my test dataframe, you get indeed a vector with numbers as OP describes.

Comment: I what way? Everything the OP is doing is fine so the only explanation is that `toappend` is not what he thinks it is. Which I say in the send line of answer (after the working example). All the later stuff is trying to show the OP that expanding outputs within loops at each iteration is stupid...

Comment: You have no idea what `conditions` looks like. `toappend` is clearly *not* what the OP thinks it is and I say that in my answer. I point out that the idiom (to quote JD Long) they are using works as long as `toappend` is a single character as that seems to be the intention.

Comment: @Gavin : given the fact that OP says that toappend looks OK (he prints it out), it seems what he thinks it is. OP selects a rowname from the input p, and does that one by one. So you get one row-index, one single value from the column 3 with that row index that goes into toappend.  That part I miss in your function, I guess together with the *10 it confused me. Toappend becomes a number when it is put in output. I guess the only explanation is that it's a factor. Nothing else I know changes characters to numbers.

Comment: @Gavin: +1 for the initiation of full length vector.

Comment: Indeed, printing is pure for debugging. I will post and example of the output. BTW conditions is a dataframe containing rownames which i Use for lookup, and I want the value in column three returned

Comment: @Timtico: see my solution then. No need to get a function, you can do that in one line.

Comment: @Joris: I guess I interpreted "spits out is a vector with numbers" in a different sense to what you did. You made the leap that the OP wasn't expecting any number characters at all. Also, you are right to point out the simplification using direct indexing - I was adding the same thing to my answer before I saw what you'd written.

Comment: @Timtico: then there is no need for a loop, just index by `p` directly. Joris and I both show that in our answers, Joris slightly before me (I'm still drinking my morning coffee).

Comment: Yes.. I had the idea that this could be done directly in some way. I'm coming from a Perl background and use loops too often in R...

Comment: @Gavin, so I would better write output[length(p)]<-character()? so it allocates a vector with the length of p (inputvector of the function?)

Comment: No, `output <- character(length = length(p))` would be the normal way to do this.

Comment: @Timtico: Look again at his code, and the help file `?character`. the function character(x) makes a character vector of length x. What you write will result in an error, as the output object doesn't exist yet, so you can't access the x'th index.

Comment: ok, you were both right. Thanks for all the (extremely fast) help guys. This makes my life easier :)